# ArcGIS tool to connect colinear polylines

Tags: line, network-analyst, topology, arcgis-10.7

I have a SHP file with thousands of polylines. Many are colinear (i.e., Line-A Endpoint-1 is same location as Line-B Endpoint-2). Sometimes they are colinaer across an intersection (as in image below), sometimes it is simpler with no intersection. In the image below, the attribute table shows 4 polylines are highlighted; I want it to just be 2 polylines.

I need to simplify the SHP file by connecting (merging) the colinear lines. Ultimately, I will be converting the lines to vertices (using `arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management()` and then `arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management()`).

Using ArcGIS 10.7 Advanced License.

**What tool (ArcPy-friendly) should I use to automatically connect colinear lines?** [image]

Comment: Have you tried Dissolve?

Comment: @BERA Tried Dissolve, it doesn't work because it retains the intersecting node and then explodes it back on the multipart conversion. I think it might work if I had a common attribute between the lines I want to connect, but I don't.

Comment: I wonder if there is a network analyst solution; I am not familiar with network analyst though

Comment: Probably, same here. I have used python library networkx for similar tasks though but it is a bit tricky.

Comment: See for example [Union of lists with common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886120/union-of-lists-with-common-elements). Your "names" in the example could be start and end XY coordinates of each line with objectid stored in each node (or is it called graph, can never remember)

Comment: @BERA I don't think that will work with the intersections